# Explanation of posterior distribution under censoring

Tags: bayesian, censoring

The question is a 2 parter. I am trying to model some data that is left censored (not time to event data) and for clarity I want to do it the same way as in the BDA3 book example here:

[image]

[image]

Question #1: Can someone explain to me why the censored part of the likelihood is
$$\Phi(\theta-200)$$
Is the likelihood for the data interpreted as just the probability of being larger than 200 under the normal model? And is that $\Phi$ the CDF of a N(0,1) evaluated at $\theta-200$?

Question #2: This is for right censored data but I have left censored data. How would the equation change for left censored data? For sake of example, you can assume I am left censored if under 200. Would it instead be
$$\Phi(\theta+200)$$

or

$$1-\Phi(\theta-200)?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, it's the probability of being greater than 200, since that is when the value is censored. If we let $X$ be the weight, and $Z := X - \theta$ be the standardised normal variable, the probability of not being greater than 200 is $P(X \leq 200) = P(Z \leq 200 -\theta)$. Since $Z$ is a standard normal variable, this is equal to $\Phi(200 - \theta)$, so we have likelihood $1 - \Phi(200 - \theta) = \Phi(\theta - 200)$.
2. In this case, censoring happens when the value is not greater than 200. This is the opposite case to that in part one, so the likelihood is just $\Phi(200 - \theta)$. The mean $\theta$ and the cutoff point $200$ have not changed, so we still use the difference $200 - \theta$, rather than changing the sign.

Comment: For part 1) you say the likelihood is equal to $\Phi(200-\theta)$ but in BDA3 they say it is $\Phi(\theta-200)$. Is there a typo in your solution?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to negate the expression. Fixed.

Comment: So in general, if you are left censored it's F(x) and if you are right censored it is 1-F(x), where F(x) is the CDF, correct?

Comment: Yes, since they're the respective probabilities of being in the censored region in those cases.